# Complete reference for scheduling

Tags: discussion

I see there are many questions and answers about scheduling. So I decided to create some sort of reference question that explains every bit of scheduling in WordPress.

- Is it even correct to create a reference question/answer and refer others to that?
- Should I ask a question and answer it by myself?
- Should my answer be a community wiki? (I don't think I have enough privileges for that)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. I don't think it is even possible to catch every detail of scheduling in WordPress in a single answer.
2. Even if it were possible – how useful would such an answer be? Do we close every other question about that topic now as duplicate, asking the OP to read a novel just to find the solution for her specific problem?
3. It is good practice to share what you have learned here in self-answered questions. So no objections to that. :)
4. Your answer should not be a community wiki. If someone else has additional information, they can write just another answer. Other edits should go through our regular review process to prevent bad edits.

Pick a specific problem. Solve it. Share it with us. We are not Wikipedia, not even the Codex. We focus on actual problems people have. If you want to write an article that explains everything that comes to your mind, do that in one of the well known magazines, they will even pay for it.

Answer (score 4):

I think the recently launched [Stack Overflow Documentation Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wordpress/topics) might be just the place for such type of content. :)

Comment: It's a bit of confusing, but I'll try :)